# Apache can't start on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, apache2, php

I have the following error that's appearing in my log errors in the file /var/log/apport.log

**ERROR: apport (pid 27860) Fri Aug  7 20:03:43 2015: called for pid 27856, signal 11
ERROR: apport (pid 27860) Fri Aug  7 20:03:43 2015: executable: /root/.scan/update (command line "./update 1500")
ERROR: apport (pid 27860) Fri Aug  7 20:03:43 2015: executable does not belong to a package, ignoring**

Everytime I type in my SSH Command :

*sudo service apache2 start*

The following error appear:

*** Starting web server apache2                                                  (20)Not a directory: apache2: could not open error log file /var/log/apache2/error.log.
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.**

and when I try to go to check the error log there's no directory called apache2 nor a file called error.log,

current version are the following

Ubuntu is 12.04 LTS

Apache 2.2.22

PHP 5.3

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

- mkdir /var/log/apache2
- touch /var/log/apache2/error.log
- touch /var/log/apache2/access.log
- chown -R root:adm /var/log/apache2
- chmod 750 /var/log/apache2
- chmod -R 540 /var/log/apache2/*
- service apache2 restart

But thats not a normal behaviour of apache2. May be you should check your server with the programm: `chkrootkit` - perhaps it was hacked or someone deleted the apache2 log dir.

Comment: I have tried the above, but with no success, other than that, the Password to the Admin that I use to access the SSH Command keep on changing. I have to reset it every once and while even though I have updated it to a very secure password.

Comment: chkrootkit, this command wasn't recognized, it stated that it requires to be installed in order for me to be able to run it? So I'm currently Installing it

Comment: Thank you for the above, I guess there's some sort of hacking as you said, anyway I just found apache file with no extension, deleted it, and run your code above and all is running smoothly now, I just need to figure out how to limit the hacking issue

Comment: @RafahNehmeh very good. If you cant get it done, I would recommend to do a clean setup again (new os, new apache and so on ...) its a lot of work, but its worth the work.